# shopt -s nocaseglob is not working on Ubuntu

Tags: shell, filenames, wildcards

Case insensitive file name globbing is not working in bash on Ubuntu 11.04 64bit. The shell options specified in `.bashrc` are as follows:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob 
shopt -s nocasematch
```

shopt also shows that `nocaseglob` and `nocasematch` are `on`. But for a directory change or opening a file, it doesn't work in case insensitivity mode.

I wish to check whether any other option is needed to enable case insensitive filename globbing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you really doing globbing, i.e. wildcard expansion? For example, suppose that you have a directory called `Foobar`. Then

```
cd foobar
```

doesn't do globbing, because there is no wildcard character. When you specify a file name exactly, it's up to the application to decide what to do with it, and since unix file names are case sensitive, the application will not open a file called `Foobar` if you tell it to open a file called `foobar`.

On the other hand,

```
cd foo*
```

will change to the `Foobar` directory (assuming there is no other match), if you've set the `nocaseglob` option.

You can make completion case-insensitive too. Put `set completion-ignore-case on` in `~/.inputrc`, or

```
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```

in `~/.bashrc`. Then after entering `cd foo` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the shell will complete `Foobar`.